# How do disable options from the Format menu in CKeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In the Format select box, you can choose Heading 1, Heading 2 etc

How can I disable some of those options? Is it also possible to rename them? I want to only allow Heading 2 and Heading 3, and if possible, rename them to Heading and Sub-Heading.

I figured out how to rename them - in the language file. I edited the 'en-au.js' and then set `{ language: 'en-au' }` but it hasn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, so I changed the titles under `en.js`, and to disable the other formats, I used this `format_tags: 'p;h3;h4'` in the config.

Comment: you can also change the config via javascript: `CKEDITOR.config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2'`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Drupal, how I ended up disabling some of the formatting options from the drop-down list was Configuration > Content Authoring > CKEditor > select profile that you want to edit > expand Advanced Options > in
Custom JavaScript configuration section, add the tags you would like to have appear in your drop-down list.  So, if you only need a p, h2, and h3, you would add the following script:

```
config.format_tags = 'p;h2;h3';
```

I referred to the following CKEDITOR page for syntax: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-format_tags

Hope this helps someone